# Add values to SQL Server where duplicates occur

Tags: sql, select, sum, duplicates

I have a table which has 2 columns 'ID' and 'Values'

I want to add values where ids are duplicated and show in another select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, sum(values)
from tbl
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```